# Looping over boolean list

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the time when a boolean value is true. But I don't understand how to code that a flipping boolean value must result in an action.

[see dataframe picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnjRv.png)

In the picture you see some values in the right column being true, the **time range** between the first and the last **true** must be calculated.

So that is the time between **2019-02-22 09:20:01** and **2019-02-22 09:50:03**

The answer must therefore be **30 minutes and 2 seconds**.

It is possible that the list is longer than this, so that somewhere else another period of **true** values start.

The code with which I experimented was the following:

```
for i in (df1['InsideArea'][:]):
  if i == 'True' and i != df1['InsideArea'][i-1]:
      start_time = df1['time'][i]
  elif i == 'False' and i != df1['InsideArea'][i-1]:
      end_time = df1['time'][i]
      df1['TimeInArea'] = (start_time - end_time)
  else:
      continue
```

I don't come further as I'm not an experienced python user.
Hope someone is able to help me.

[CSV FILE OF DATAFRAME](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VQ33smJ2f0bjobbmUgI184sMM8Ld5CpD/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The posted code has syntax errors.

Comment: You want to store the index of when you previously observed a `true` value, so when you observe it next time, you can take the time difference between `current` and `previous` times. Then, you update the `previous` value to the `current value` and repeat.
Please update your code with the right syntax and logic and edit the question if you experience any errors in the code.

Comment: what is type of "i" ? you once check it as a string, then use it as an integer for the array index...

Comment: `df['flip']` is a column and you are setting all of its values to `'flip'` or `'no_flip'`

Comment: Changed my code, but it's still not working...

Comment: So syntax errors are gone!

Comment: @C.Snoeij There are no times in your attached file. Also don't use `'True'` and `'False'` to compare with booleans. Use `True` and `False`. Also you are mixing `i` as a value of current row and as an index of this row. And it's not understable how you want your result to be presented. It can't be in table as its size is not the same as number of columns in table.

Comment: FYI your download file has no times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
times = df1.index[1:][df1.iloc[1:, 1].reset_index(drop=True) != df1.iloc[:-1, 1].reset_index(drop=True)]
print(times[1::2] - times[0::2])
```

Comment: It's good practice on Stack Overflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work or is better than the existing solutions. For more information read [How To Answer](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).